# How do I enable Node.js integration in webview electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Whenever I try to load an HTML file with webview that has a javascript file that requires node.js the node.js integration does not work (I just tried to use require).

Here is my webview code

```
<webview id = 'frame' src = 'Home/home.html' style="max-width: 75%; min-width: 75%; height: 100%; padding-left: 10px; position:absolute; top:0; left: 175px;" nodeintegration></webview>
```

here are my main.js web preferences

```
webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      webviewTag: true,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out but the way you integrate node.js is to disable context isolation so like this

```
<webview webpreferences = 'contextIsolation=false'></webview>
```